# Long strings in Qml TextField

Tags: qt, qml, textfield

In my project I use QML TextField. I want correctly represent cursor when long strings are used. The main problem arise, when we set cursor on the middle of string and we start typing text. In this case text appears on left side from cursor, but it doesn't move's cursor! I want to create cursor moving to right side while typing text, until it reaches right side.

```
TextField {
    font.pixelSize: parent.height * 0.7

    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

    text: parent.text

    cursorPosition: parent.cursorPosition
    cursorVisible: true
}
```

Comment: have tried your code eliminating `text: parent.text` and `cursorPosition: parent.cursorPosition` and it works correctly, you could provide a [mcve], for example when I run your code I get an error because parent is not defined, also not you indicate what type the parent is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in text editing method. I used Q_PROPERTY() for it. When text is changed, text in TextField deletes completely and then new text pasted. It moves cursor at the end of line and then, cursor setting in Q_PROPERTY() causes the problem described above.

The solution is using TextField methods, like remove() and insert().